# Actionscript: How can I create a counter that registers a hitTestObject and shows the score on the main stage?

Tags: function, actionscript-3, text, actionscript, counter

My game counts the number of hits to an object and brings the user either to a winning or losing page. How can my hitTestObject count the number of hits while showing the number on the main stage? If the user hits "friend" 5 times, I want it to play the "youWin" layer and if they hit a "biter" once, I want it to play the "youLose" layer. (Please help this is for my final project and I'm almost done) Thank you! :)

```
stop();

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,fishHit);

function fishHit(e:Event){
    if (theFish.hitTestObject(biter)){
        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,fishHit);
        gotoAndPlay("youLose");
}
}

var theFish:fish = new fish();
theFish.x = 200
theFish.y = 260
addChild(theFish);

for (var which=0; which<5; which++){
    var biter:shark=new shark();
    biter.x=1400;
    biter.y=int(Math.random()*660.0+30.0);
    addChild(biter);
}

for (var what=0; what<5; what++){
    var friend:starfish=new starfish();
    friend.x=1400;
    friend.y=int(Math.random()*660.0+30.0);
    addChild(friend);
}

var counter : int = 0;
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,winner);

function winner (e:Event){
    if(theFish.hitTestObject(friend)) {
        counter +=  1
        scoreboard.score_text.text = counter;
        if(counter == 5)
            removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,winner);
            gotoAndPlay("youWin");

    }
}
```

Comment: So what does not work as expected? By the way, once theFish hits a friend, you want to remove that theFish, so it does not increase counter variable on each frame. Also, you need only one event.ENTER_FRAME function.

Comment: When I run the program, the counter doesn't count up when I hit the "friend". It also gives me this error: TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference. at Final_Game_fla::MainTimeline/winner()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need many updates in your code, but I'll try to copy and paste your code with small modifications. You should define your variables outside of for loop, also you must add multiple objects like 'friends' to an array.

```
stop();

// arrays
var friends:Array = new Array();
var biters:Array = new Array();

var counter : int = 0;

var theFish:fish = new fish();
theFish.x = 200
theFish.y = 260
addChild(theFish);

for (var which=0; which<5; which++){
    var biter = new shark();
    biter.x=1400;
    biter.y=int(Math.random()*660.0+30.0);
    addChild(biter);

    // push it to the array
    biters.push(biter)
}

for (var what=0; what<5; what++){
    var friend = new starfish();
    friend.x=1400;
    friend.y=int(Math.random()*660.0+30.0);
    addChild(friend);

    // push it to the array
    friends.push(friend)
}

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrame);

function enterFrame(e:Event){

// theFish vs biters
for (var i:int = 0; i < biters.length; i++){
    if (theFish.hitTestObject(biters[i])){
        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrame);
        gotoAndPlay("youLose");
}
}

// theFish and friends
for (i = 0; i < friends.length; i++){
    if(theFish.hitTestObject(friends[i])) {

        // remove this friend so it does not increase counter
        friends.splice(i,1);
        counter +=  1
        scoreboard.score_text.text = counter;
        if(counter == 5){
            removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrame);
            gotoAndPlay("youWin");
         }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this! The only thing is that the counter still doesn't work. I have the text of the counter made as a symbol named score_text, is that right?

Comment: var myText:TextField = new TextField();
myText.text = counter.toString();     It should be something like that. If you find the answer helpful, consider upvoting it or accepting it.